# Linear Algebra: Matrix Spanning/Consistency Question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

1) If there are $5$ vectors found in $\mathbb{R}^7$ will these vectors Span $\mathbb{R}^7$? Please explain.

2) Give an example of a $3$ by $5$ matrix for which all systems, $Ax=b$ for any $b$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is found to be consistent.

3) Given the last question, is it possible to find a $5$ by $3$ matrix with the property in the last question?

Comment: Does anyone have an idea on how to do questions 2 and 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As others have said, 5 vectors will at most span a 5–dimensional subspace of $\mathbb R ^7$.
2. $A$ will map $\mathbb R^5$ to some part of $\mathbb R^3$. The columns of A indicate to where each unit vector $e_1=(1,0,0,0,0), \dots, e_5=(0,0,0,0,1)$ from the canonical basis is mapped, and thus, $Ax$ will represent a linear combination of its columns: $x_1Ae_1+\dots+x_5Ae_5$. So... in order for the equation $Ax=b$ to make sense for every $b$ you need to be able to span the whole of $\mathbb R^3$ with the columns of $A$. Think of linear dependency. To give a very simple example, think of something like an "identity".
3. Continuing with the previous argument, you would have to span the whole of $\mathbb R^5$ with columns of $A$ now. Is that possible? The answer relates to question 1.

Answer (score 0):

1) The dimension of $\mathbb R^7$ is $7$. All bases of a vector space have the same number of elements, so the base for $\mathbb R^7$ has $7$ elements. This means $5$ vectors can never span $\mathbb R^7$.

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

By a dimension counting argument, you should see that you are lacking at least 2 vectors. Maybe more if your initial $5$ vectors were not linearly independent in the first place.