# determine whether the equation $Ax = b$ is consistent for every $b$ in $\mathbb R^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I have two problems, the first one is the following matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0\\ -2 & 1\end{bmatrix}$$
where the RREF is
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
and where the answer is *yes*.

The second is the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\\0&1\\-2&2\end{bmatrix}$$

where the RREF is
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\\ 0&4\end{bmatrix}$$
and where the answer is *no*

Can someone walk me through the reasoning behind the first answer being yes and the second one being no?

Comment: See my comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/672234/123170). Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What needs walking through: bringing a matrix to RREF? finding whether $Ax=b$ is consistent when $A$ is in RREF? understanding why the answer for RREF implies the answer for the original matrix?

Comment: finding whether Ax=b is consistent when A is in RREF. From my understanding if a row is 0, which everything under the pivot point  is, then it should not be consistent yet the first one for the answer says it is consistent and the second one says no. Is this not how you go about finding whether an equation is consistent?

Comment: What is a RREF?

Comment: @user2943324 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form

Comment: Actually, the RREF for the second matrix is $$\pmatrix{1&0\cr0&1\cr0&0\cr}$$

Comment: Note that for the first matrix there is no row consisting entirely of zeros (this is a more precise way of saying "a row is $0$") in the RREF, whereas for the second matrix, there is such a row (when you do the RREF right). So this is consistent with your understanding of when the equations are guaranteed to be consistent, and when they may not be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

You already calculated the RREF for both matrices, so you only have to draw the conclusions.

For the first, you have the RREF of 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
meaning you can transform an equation $Ax=b$ (by transforming $b$ into  $\tilde b$)
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\tilde b_1\\ \tilde b_2\end{bmatrix}$$ which you can obviously always solve.

In the second case, you can transform the equation into
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & -1\\ 0 & 1\\ 0&4\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\tilde b_1\\ \tilde b_2\\ \tilde b_3\end{bmatrix}.$$

It is clear that because this gives you equations 
$$x_2=\tilde b_2$$
and
$$4x_2 = \tilde b_3$$
that the solution may not always exist.

Answer (score 0):

Recheck the ref of the second matrix, the reasoning of this answer is correct regardless, but you have the wrong ref.